# How to retrieve data from Firebase using Python?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Firebase and I'm trying to retrieve some test data that I created. I'm able to connect to the database, as I get a return value of 0.
When I try to pull data, I get None as the result. I'm expecting the data in the database to be retrieve.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

cred = credentials.Certificate("Path to Json fire")


firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {'databaseURL': 'Database URL'})

ref = db.reference('Secret')

results = ref.child("test").get()

print(results)
```

I'm expecting the results to return the data in my database. However, I'm getting the result None.

Comment: I'm assuming that where you have `"Path to Json fire"` and `'Database URL'` you have actual values for your database but just didn't want to show them here?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I wasn't sure of the security concern around that, so I put that data instead.

Answer (score 0):

check the name of the folder in which you have the information again. If it is mentioned wrong, then data would be returned none.